# How to center items in a list without using margin inside lists?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

here i have 2 lists where i want items from the left list be draggable to the right list and the items must be sortable in the right list but i can't.
i have to center the draggable items in the sortable2 (the one on the left) but I DON'T WANT TO USE MARGIN because it will cause bugs in the code while dragging. is there any other method i'm not aware of for centering these items?
here is the code:

```js
$(function() {
        $( "#sortable1 li" ).draggable({
   cursor:"move", cursorAt:{top:50, left:40},
            connectToSortable: ".connectedSortable",
            helper:"clone",
   revert:150,
            remove: function(event, ui) {
                ui.item.clone().appendTo('#sortable2');
                $(this).draggable('cancel');
            }
        }).disableSelection();
    
 
 
 
 
 
    $( "#sortable2" ).sortable({
  axis:"y",
  placeholder: "slide-placeholder",
     start:function(e,ui){
        
        placeholderHeight = ui.item.outerHeight();
        ui.placeholder.height(placeholderHeight + 15);
        $('<div class="slide-placeholder-animator" data-height="' + placeholderHeight + '"></div>').insertAfter(ui.placeholder);
    
    },
    change: function(event, ui) {
        
        ui.placeholder.stop().height(0).animate({
            height: ui.item.outerHeight() + 15
        }, 300);
        
        placeholderAnimatorHeight = parseInt($(".slide-placeholder-animator").attr("data-height"));
        
        $(".slide-placeholder-animator").stop().height(placeholderAnimatorHeight + 15).animate({
            height: 0
        }, 300, function() {
            $(this).remove();
            placeholderHeight = ui.item.outerHeight();
            $('<div class="slide-placeholder-animator" data-height="' + placeholderHeight + '"></div>').insertAfter(ui.placeholder);
        });
        
    },
    stop: function(e, ui) {
        
        $(".slide-placeholder-animator").remove();
        
    },
        }).disableSelection();
    });
```

```css
<style>
    #sortable1 { list-style-type: none; margin: auto; padding: 0; float: right; }
    #sortable2 { list-style-type: none; margin: auto; padding: 0; float: left; min-height:130px; width:130px; border:1px solid black; }
    #sortable1 li { margin:10px 0px; padding: 1px; font-size: 1.2em; line-height:100px; width: 70px; height: 100px; border-radius:10%; color:#ffffff; box-shadow:3px 3px 1px #888888; }
    #sortable2 li {position:relative; margin:10px 0px; padding: 1px; font-size: 1.2em; line-height:100px; width: 70px; height: 100px; border-radius:10%; color:#ffffff; box-shadow:3px 3px 1px #888888; }
    .red{background-color:#ff3300;}
    .blue{background-color:#1111ff;}
    .black{background-color:#000000;}
    .green{background-color:#00fd01;}
    .yellow{background-color:#ffff66;}
    .slide-placeholder{height:100px; background-color:#DADADA; border:1px dotted red;  -webkit-box-shadow: none; -moz-box-shadow: none; box-shadow: none; }


   </style>
```

```html
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<body>
   <ul id="sortable1">
    <li class="ui-state-default red">Item 1</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default blue">Item 2</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default black">Item 3</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default green">Item 4</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default yellow">Item 5</li>
   </ul>

   <ul id="sortable2" class="connectedSortable">

   </ul>



 </body>
```

Comment: i got error result from your snippet, anything wrong? please check

Comment: @raksaeng fixed!